# Proving injectivity of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, gamma-function

Let *I* denote the interval $(0,\infty)$, we define the function $f:I^2\to I^2$ by,
$$f(x,y)=\left({\Gamma(4x+y)\Gamma(y)\over {\Gamma(2x+y)}^2},{\Gamma(4x+y)\Gamma(2x+y)\over {\Gamma(3x+y)}^2}\right)$$
where, $\Gamma()$ is the gamma function.

It has been observed numerically that this function is injective in its domain, but how can we prove that?

Comment: By "observed numerically" do you mean you have checked for several values of $x$ and $y$? If so, how many values have you checked?

Comment: Yes i do. I checked millions of random values in domain and all of them approved the injectivity. also, if we change the domain of function to, $f:I \times \mathbb{N}  \to I^2$, where, $\mathbb{N}$ is "all positive integers", then we can easily prove that the function $f$ is an injective function.